# Add a timestamp field to a table in SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, database, timestamp

I'm modifying some c# code and attempting to add a date+time field to a database when it is created. What would be a good method to do this? I'm new to SQL and databases, so pointing me to helpful resources is also appreciated.

I believe I want something like:

```
createCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Table1 ( field1 INTEGER, field2 BLOB, timestamp datatype);"
```

I am unsure of what datatype to use for a time and date marker. Should I use text and have it be in the form of "12/19/2012, 16:20"? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use a string type, you should use a format that sorts chronologically in alphabetical order. SQLite's buit-in functions support ISO 8601 strings (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS) as well as Julian day numbers and Unix-style integer timestamps.

See: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime and http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html